# Getting value from Javascript before page load event in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dom-events

I would like to know how I can execute Javascript before Page_Load event (if that's possible of course). I am trying to get user's local time with Javascript and I am getting correctly, but I want to get that before I am at the page_load event because I want to play with that value in the page_load event.
Is that possible?

Comment: Try and provide a bit more information about what you are actually trying to achieve. You will likely find that it can be done is some sort of alternative fashion to intercepting the page_load event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible. Page_Load happens on the server before a page is rendered and sent to the client where the Javascript is executed.